# What do I do if I want to make two separate ports for the same ip

Tags: windows-10

Sorry, I'm new to this. Say for example I want to open cod world at war port so I have an open NAT and I also want to open black ops 2 port to also have an open NAT on the same ip, do I make it in the same section or separate sections. I tried making another section but it said I would have to delete my other one? If the case is that I put open both ports in the same section, what do I do if there isn't enough space for the ports? Thanks for the help

Comment: first, what do you mean by "Sections", and second, will both programs be on the same PC?

Comment: @FrankThomas they're games from the Call of Duty series. Its very likely to assume they're on the same pc, given that OP talks about `the same ip` in his title.

Comment: fair enough, but when people talk about a single IP in NAT scenarios, they are usually talking about the public IP, not the internal LAN, so its a valid question. Most routers can't NAT more than one device on the same port (eg there can only be one forward rule for TCP\80, and it must target a single LAN IP address), so if the programs need the same port, and are run one at a time, there is no reason to create additional rules for each game, one rule per port will do it.

Comment: A switch will let you do this, most routers won't let you do this, connect the PC(s) to the switch which is connected to a router.

Answer (score 0):

Opening ports on your router to one ip can be separated or in one section if your router understands it. It is basically upto the router on how it deals with this. Some router can only have one item per IP address, but below, you can have many ports configured.

Other rounters only can have one port per entry, but it doesn't really care for which port and/or ip is used as long as its following the proper guideline.

And yet another router can have both mixed (as in, allowing one or more ports per ip address per entry, allowing more entries for one ip addres.

So do whatever works, as it doesn't really matter for the outcome.